# Troubleshooting Web Service Consumption

Tags: wcf, web-services, .net-3.5

I am attempting to connect to hosted solution's web service. The solution takes an xml query and returns an xml resultset via soap.

When I connect to the WSDL using a .Net 3.5 service, the code will not compile due to ambiguity errors.  When I connect using a .Net 2.0 Web Service the project compiles and when I build the xml query and send it to the service I get back what is expected except two fields of the same type that are not filled in properly. When I check the xml coming back with Fiddler I am getting the data for that field, it would seem somewhere in the reference code that data doesn't make it to the generated service object. I am not really expecting an answer as to why from anyone but I am at a loss for my next step in the troubleshooting process.

Since the data comes back from the service it is getting lost somewhere in the reference code and how it is getting put back in the object.  I would appreciate any help on where to look next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the schema being consumed use attributes? If so, try either forcing svcutil to use XmlSerializer serialization using the `/serializer:XmlSerializer` command line option or you can try to use the `/importXmlTypes` switch will will import any types that don't fit the data contract patterns as an `IXmlSerializable` implementation.